# Mixing radio buttons and text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, textfield

I'm trying to combine radio buttons and text_field for a single value :

```
= f.radio_button :system, "bacteria"
Bacteria
= f.radio_button :system, "mammalian"
Mammalian
= f.radio_button :system, "yeast"
Yeast
= f.radio_button :system, "insect"
Insect
= f.radio_button :system, "other"
Other:
= f.text_field :system, class:"input-small"
```

When I submit, nothing happens because a blank value is given in params even if a radio is checked (I think it considers the text field).

I tried to give another name to the text_field, and replaced the :system value in the controller after updating, but it looks like a dirty way...

Do you have any cleaner ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can not directly mix radio_button and text_field together for the same field.
I think you can define one extra radio_button field that will be hidden and whose value will get updated when user enters into text_field.

```
= f.radio_button :system, "bacteria"
Bacteria
= f.radio_button :system, "mammalian"
Mammalian
= f.radio_button :system, "yeast"
Yeast
= f.radio_button :system, "insect"
Insect
= f.radio_button :system, "other"
Other:
= f.radio_button :system, nil, :id => :hidden_radio, :style => "display:none"
= f.text_field :free_system_input, class:"input-small", :id => :free_system_input
```

In above you will be writing onchange event on text_field and whenever value gets entered inside text_field it will set hidden radio_button's value to the text_field_value.

```
:javascript
 $("free_system_input").keyup(function(){
   $("hidden_radio").val($(this).val())
 })
```

Above code is just to give idea how to deal with issue and will not work just as it is .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sandip's help, I managed to fix my problem!

Here is the view:

```
= f.radio_button :system, "bacteria"
Bacteria
= f.radio_button :system, "mammalian"
Mammalian
= f.radio_button :system, "yeast"
Yeast
= f.radio_button :system, "insect"
Insect
%br/
= f.radio_button :system, nil, id: 'other_system_radio', 
                checked: radio_checked?('system', f.object.system) 
Other:
%input.input-small#other_system_text{ value: text_input?('system', f.object.system) }
```

I use helper functions to manage edit form (fill the text field if the value if different from the given ones):

```
def radio_checked?(type,val)
  case type
    when 'system'
      ['bacteria', 'mammalian', 'yeast', 'insect'].include?(val) ? '' : 'checked'               
    end
  end

def text_input?(type,val)
  case type
    when 'system'
      ['bacteria', 'mammalian', 'yeast', 'insect'].include?(val) ? '' : val
  end       
end
```

And a bit of Javascript to select the "Other" radio button when the user focuses on the text field:

```
@handle_other_field = ->
  $('#other_system_text').focus( -> $('#other_system_radio').attr('checked','checked'))
  $('#other_system_text').keyup( -> $('#other_system_radio').val($(this).val()))
```