# Using Rails 3.2 and Rails form - don't know how to display an input text field when a radio button is checked true and hide it otherwise

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I fetched couple posts over here but I am still unable to make it work.
When "Other" radio button is checked I would like a f.text_field to show up and when is unchecked to be hidden.
I would like after that to be able to input a text value for thr attribute f.client_consent_refusal_reason.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= form_for(@client, :url => {:controller => 'client', :action=> :outcome_consent_complete, :id => @client.id }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'Hearing loss', :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'aaa' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'bbb', :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'ccc' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'ddd', :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'eee' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'fff', :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'ggg' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'Other', :checked => false %>
        <%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'Other' %>
        <%= f.text_field :client_consent_refusal_reason %>
        <br><br>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When any of the above radio buttons are checked the field client_consent_refusal_reason should be set to the associated value, but when Other is checked, I would like to be able to capture the correspondent value.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced this part of the code:

```
<%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'Other', :checked => false %>
<%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'Other' %>
<%= f.text_field :client_consent_refusal_reason %>
```

with this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :client_consent_refusal_reason, 'Other', :checked => false,
    :onchange => "$('other_reason_input')[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();" %>
<%= f.label :radio_button_label, 'Other (please list): ' %>

<div id="other_reason_input" style="display:none;">
  <%= f.text_field :client_consent_refusal_reason_other %>
</div>
```

And in the model class I had to add these lines:

```
  attr_accessor :client_consent_refusal_reason_other

  def client_consent_refusal_reason_other=(value)
    self.client_consent_refusal_reason = value if client_consent_refusal_reason == 'Other'
  end

  def client_consent_refusal_reason_other
    client_consent_refusal_reason
  end
```

Now everything is working as expected.